# adding search bar under the navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i want to add a search bar under the navigation bar with uitableview.
and i want to search from the database?
any idea how to do this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add the searchbar as the headerView for your table.

```
UISearchBar *temp = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
temp.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
temp.showsCancelButton=YES;
temp.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
temp.autocapitalizationType=UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
temp.delegate=self;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView=temp;
[temp release];
```